# what is the difference between these methods of RequestContextHolder , currentRequestAttributes() and getRequestAttributes()?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, httprequest

I am trying to use `RequestContextHolder`, in this class we have two methods `currentRequestAttributes()` and `getRequestAttributes()` what is the difference between these methods ?

I saw these two methods have the same meaning, then why we have two methods ?

My requirement is I want to set one attribute in the currently processing request in one class of my application, and use it in another class of the same application for the same request processing ,so I thought of using the `RequestContextHolder`, but I found those two methods with the same meaning which one is more meaningful for my problem ?

**Note:** Reason why am using this class is I do not want to pass the flag calculated in the class, all the way to the starting class of the spring boot app , because if I want to pass , then I need to change the all method signatures in that call stack , so many method signatures I might need change, and in that this flag is calculated per request , I decided to go with that class `RequestContextHolder`.

Comment: You can read the source code: `currentRequestAttributes()` is just `getRequestAttributes()` + `if ( getRequestAttributes() == null)` fallback to `FacesRequestAttributesFactory.getFacesRequestAttributes();` + if null throw exception https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.java#L99-L140

Comment: @varren , thanks for pointing to the useful link , now i got that infact currentRequestAttributes() is calling getRequestAttributes() , and for pure spring boot application (not JSF apps) , we better to call getRequestAttributes() only , thanks once again for the help .

Answer (score 4):

This is the source code for *getRequestAttributes*;

```
public static RequestAttributes getRequestAttributes() {
    RequestAttributes attributes = requestAttributesHolder.get();
    if (attributes == null) {
        attributes = inheritableRequestAttributesHolder.get();
    }
    return attributes;
}
```

And *currentRequestAttributes*;

```
public static RequestAttributes currentRequestAttributes() throws IllegalStateException {
    RequestAttributes attributes = getRequestAttributes();
    if (attributes == null) {
        if (jsfPresent) {
            attributes = FacesRequestAttributesFactory.getFacesRequestAttributes();
        }
        if (attributes == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No thread-bound request found: " +
                    "Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, " +
                    "or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? " +
                    "If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, " +
                    "your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: " +
                    "In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.");
        }
    }
    return attributes;
}
```

It seems *currentRequestAttributes* is calling *getRequestAttributes* first. And currentRequestAttributes checks if request is in a JSF environment and if so it returns FacesContext parameters. In your case you will only set a parameter yourself and use it somewhere else, so **getRequestAttributes** method should do your job.

Comment: yes you mentioned correct and varren  , pointed me in that direction , thanks for the code Doğukan Zengin